# Is it possible to get width of terminal or to print line with fill of 100% width?

Tags: php, terminal, command-line-interface

PHP. `fputs(STDOUT, 'some short text')`!
Is there any way to get char length for terminal that launch php script?

How to print text with `fputs(STDOUT, "Some Error\n");` with full line background of red color?

Comment: It depends a lot on the OS and the terminal software. If you are on Linux or macOS and the environment variable `COLUMNS` is set (and not empty) then it contains the terminal width you want (or the width of the terminal at some point in the past).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will output a line with "=" characters filling the whole line of the terminal. Will work on linux-based system.

```
// 'tput cols' is a shell command which returns
//   the number of chars to fill up the whole
//   line of the current terminal.
$colCount = shell_exec('tput cols');

// Create the string filling the whole line
$string = str_repeat("=", intval($colCount));

// This is the way to print out text with coloured background
// 48, 5, 160 representing 256-colour of red, green and blue.
fputs(STDOUT, "\e[48;5;160m".$string."\e[0m");
```

Which can be condensed to one line

```
fputs(STDOUT, "\e[48;5;160m".str_repeat("=", intval(shell_exec('tput cols')))."\e[0m");
```

[Here's a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal) to ANSI color code in XTerm/ANSI-compatible terminals with a 256-color palette support if you want to know more about displaying colours on terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Symfony\Console for this, since it has `Terminal` class that does exactly what you need:

#### Install with composer

```
composer require symfony/console
```

#### Create script `index.php`

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$terminal = new Symfony\Component\Console\Terminal;

$terminalWidth = $terminal->getWidth();
var_dump($terminalWidth);
```

#### Test it

```
$ php index.php
int(80)
```

Comment: A actually worked on this class to be decoupled from code and usable more standalone like this. It should cover all OS differences.